# Erro no Angular TypeError: _co.desabilitar is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Gostaria de entender o que está causando esse erro na minha aplicação.
Segue os códigos:

```
desabilitar(elemento){
var radio = document.getElementById(elemento) as HTMLInputElement;
radio.checked = false;
}



<mat-radio-button class="margem" value=1 (change)="getRadioValorR($event)" click="desabilitar(G0)">1</mat-radio-button>

<mat-radio-button id="G0" name="G0" *ngIf="!getClass0()" class="margem" value="0" disabled>0</mat-radio-button>
```